# How to fix CORS error: MethodDisallowedByPreflightResponse in ASP .NET C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, cors, preflight

### The Problem

Sending an http request to an ASP.NET Core API server (although I believe this will apply to a variety of different .NET style servers) I get the CORS error: `MethodDisallowedByPreflightResponse`. I specifically am getting this error on a PUT request (it does not occur on POST or GET requests).

#### What I tried:

- Googling, no one else has written about this specific error.
- DevTools Network tab (ie. inspecting the actual Http request headers and content)... There is nothing in the preflight request/response that seems to indicate anything about which methods are allowed and which aren't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### My Answer:

Looking at my server's CORS settings, I realized that the `.AllowAnyHeader()` method on the Cors middleware might indicate there is a similar method for allowing any Methods. I was correct.

**Use `.AllowAnyMethod()` to fix this error (assuming you actually want to allow any http method type).**

Here is where you specifically put this on your server (I'm using ASP.NET CORE API, version 5 I believe) :

```
//Startup.cs

//.... in the "Startup" class "ConfigureServices" method....
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddDefaultPolicy(
                    builder =>
                    {
                        builder.WithOrigins("https://example.com")
                            .AllowAnyHeader()
                            .AllowAnyMethod(); //THIS LINE RIGHT HERE IS WHAT YOU NEED
                    });
            });

// ... the rest of your code, other middleware, etc.
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. Answer helped me solve the same problem, thanks!